# Complement child styles from parent ones (SCSS + CSS-Modules)

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-css-modules

I have the following files and React structure:

**1. header.scss**

```
.header { ...header styles }
```

**2. home.scss**

```
@use './header.scss'

.home {
  
   .header {
     background-color: red;
   }
    
}
```

**3. component.js(React)**

```js
  import homeStyles from "./home.scss";
  import headerStyles from "./header.scss" 

...
  <div className={homeStyles.home}>
     <div className={headerStyles.header}>...</div>
  </div>
...
```

So, as you can see, I use React and css-modules. The goal is to complement `.header` class from `home.scss` styles in `home.scss`. Currently, I can't get this code working (Background color setting isn't applied). Is there any way to achieve this result?

Comment: why not add 2 variables for the import of `./home.scss` and use one for the header? If the original home import works, I don't see a reason to import it twie.

Comment: @ZombieChowder, I want the header to be independent. It just contains needed styles for the header, but `home.css` know how to position and adjust things inside.

Answer (score 0):

Suggests importing the `header.scss` file into `home.scss`
`@import "./header.scss";`
Then import only 1 scss file into the javascript file.

If you're using the compiler: to make sure both files are not compiled, add char `_` before the file name `_header.scss`

Comment: It will import your whole styles into one scss file, which will be used in the Javascript code.
However, @import header should be added rather at the end if you have something else written in the home.scss file.

Comment: Remember that you have to use a compiler for Sass. Either webpack or, for example, the gulp. There are many of them. The browser does not understand the code of scss.  It only understands css.